# Jira: Query all stories that belong to a different project than the Epic itself

Tags: jira

In Jira I want to query all stories that belong to a different project than the Epic itself.

For example:
My Epic is in project Y. The Epic contains 5 stories in project Y but one story in project Z.

Now I want to show on a board only the stories that belong to different projects than the epic they belong to.

The goal is to create a board that gives me an overview of dependencies on other projects than my own.

Can anyone please advise how I can accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Try This JQL query

```
Project!="YourProject" and issuetype=Story and "Epic Link" in (XXX-###, YYY-###)
```

[Advanced scearching](https://confluence.atlassian.com/jiracorecloud/advanced-searching-765593707.html)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. 
It does not solve my issue.
The Epic is in project X, most stories of the epic are also in project X. But some of stories of the epic are in project Y and Z. I want to see such stories on my  board.

As extra challenge. There are 8 projects and 100 epics.

Comment: @Anton, I understood your issue BUT there is no straight resolution for that.

The main problem is that creating nested JQL query is not possible. So you cannot just get all epics on your project and find all related issue from other project. This feature has been reported on atlassian service desk but it still not implemented:

[JRASERVER-21936](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/JRASERVER-21936)

The only way to done this is to get all issues related to epic on your project. Then to exclude (!=) issues from your project. Disadvantage is that you need to type all keys of your epics.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the Adaptavist ScriptRunner plugin you can complete this: issueFunction in issuesInEpics("project = XXX" AND project not in (XXX)

This should return all cards that are from outside projects.